# C++ static dispatch with custom initialization

Tags: c++, static, bitset, dispatch, crtp

I would like to use CRTP for a performance-sensitive section of my code. However, my base class has a bitset, which size depends on the derived class. I was hoping that something like that would work:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Base {
protected:
    std::bitset<Derived::bsize> data_;
};

class Foo : public Base<Foo> {
public:
    constexpr static size_t bsize = 2;
};
```

but the compiler complains: "no member bsize in Foo". I guess I could solve my problem by templating the bitset length too in the base class:

```
template <typename Derived, size_t size>
class Base {
protected:
    std::bitset<size> data_;
};

class Foo : public Base<Foo,2> { ... };
```

In the future, I might want to have more complex expressions to compute the bitset length. Is there a way to get the job done using constexpr functions? (closer in spirit to my first non-working solution)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: You cannot do this with CRTP in C++. What's happening is when `Base<Foo>` is instantiated, `Foo::bsize` does not exist yet. This is because that happens when the compiler sees `Base<Foo>` on the `Foo` class, which is before your `{`. It's not *quite* as simple as that, but that's the general idea.

There is a workaround to do what you want here, which is to bundle all the necessary information in a class, then supply it as a template parameter. I do not know the name of this pattern (I've seen "baggage class," but that feels pejorative), but you can find examples of this in the standard library, such as [`std::char_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits).

```
class FooTraits {
    constexpr static size_t bsize = 2;
};

template <class Traits = FooTraits>
class BasicFoo {
protected:
    std::bitset<Traits::bsize> data_;
};
```

Traits are pretty flexible -- you can just drop a `static constexpr` function into your `FooTraits` to calculate whatever you need to. In your case, the derived class would pass a derived-type-specific version of `FooTraits` to the `Traits` template argument of `BasicFoo`.

It is worth noting that your milage may vary. While flexible, the problem with traits is that someone wanting to implement the concept of `FooTraits` needs to make sure they implement all the things `BasicFoo` needs or they will get a horrible compilation error (in C++20, this is helped via [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)). Without careful thought, traits can become a dumping ground of things, which makes implementing an alternative `FooTraits` even harder.